# C# How to access the current playback of windows

Tags: c#, windows, playback, audio-player

at Windows 10 there is a Music Feature(Pic Below):
[image: Music Feature]

So my Question is: How can I access this information with C# and which libraries do i need?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excuse me for my ignorance, but if I am correct, this widget is a pop up of Spotify, isn't this? In that case, you only have to check the *MainWindowsTitle* of spotify process.

```
        var spotify = Process.GetProcessesByName("Spotify");
        foreach (var song in spotify)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(song.MainWindowTitle);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Don't forget use `using System.Diagnostics;`. You will have to check if you don't get any song.

I was checking if this method works yet :) [image]

Comment: Okay i didn´t expect that because it also shows up in Lock-Screen.

http://i.imgur.com/DFKVOZj.jpg

hm then i got a problem^^ But thank u

Comment: Hm i just started a little "lock  screen" with a clock, weather, calendar, todo´s .. and now i wanted to add the current playback. But if this is not a windows standard then i only can access spotify. Maybe im going to implement this, but i´m not sure

Comment: Shouldn't it say `Console.WriteLine(song.MainWindowTitle);`? :)